# USB peripherals reconnecting and finally disconnecting when on battery power with CyberPower CP1500EPFCLCD UPS

Tags: usb, ups

The following happens with my brand new, fully charged CP1500EPFCLCD UPS by CyberPower if I cut power to it (with the home circuit breaker): After a few seconds, my USB mouse starts reconnecting (i.e. stops working and then starts working again) every few seconds, if it were pulled out and plugged in again. Similarly, the companion app, PowerPanel Personal loses connection to the UPS every few seconds (the UPS is connected via USB too). My Bluetooth keyboard stops working altogether (it's connecting to my motherboard's built-in Bluetooth). The USB reconnects become more and more frequent, and then, after 3-4 minutes of battery runtime, all USB peripherals stop working.

The final step is at more than 80% battery capacity remaining (with a supposed >25 minutes of runtime remaining), with UPS load being at most 225W but usually below 200W (the output power limit of this UPS is 900W).

If I restore power, everything starts working immediately.

All this is under Windows 10. The self-test of the UPS passes. I have no issues with my PC and its peripherals otherwise.

Disabling power-saving features doesn't help:

- In Device Manager, under Universal Serial Bus controllers I've gone through all of their properties, and where there was a Power Management tab, I unchecked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".
- Under Power Options of the Control Panel I've changed the settings of the current plan to disable "USB selective suspend setting".

I had found no relevant resources on the web. Does anybody have any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an USB hub. Removing that USB hub, and plugging in the three devices it served directly into USB ports on my motherboard works fine.

It's perhaps not the hub per se; when I plugged it in alone, nothing bad happened. Rather, I'm speculating that a single USB port serving multiple devices (a standard keyboard, the UPS, and a standard mouse) somehow caused haywire.